# Python: Sharing Class Variables Between Multiple Classes

Tags: python, multithreading, class

My problem is how to share a variable or a buffer between more than one class
e.g. writing into a single buffer from multiple classes knowing that some classes are running in a threaded environment
example

```
class my1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer=[0]*5
        self.size=0
    def insert(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.buffer[self.size]=self.data
        self.size+=1

class my2(my1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.insert('data1')

class my3(my1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.insert('data2')
```

The desired result would be the buffer containing both data1 and data2 to be processed
yet the buffer within class my1 is defined inside the (**init**) section and cannot be shared 
any suggestions?
Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.

Just create an object of class `my1` and pass it to objects of class `my2` and `my3`.

```
# leave my1 as it is

class my2(): # no need to inherit from my1
    def __init__(self, my1obj): # buffer is object of my1
        my1obj.insert('data1')

class my3():
    def __init__(self, my1obj):
        my1obj.insert('data2')

mybuffer = my1()
my2obj = my2(mybuffer)
my3obj = my3(mybuffer)
```

Comment: *"some classes are running in a threaded environment"* The `.insert()` method as written in the question is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want the buffer to be bound to the `My1` class, you can use a static class variable

```
class My1(object):
    buffer = [0] * 5
```